# combining 2 dataframes with NO COMMON columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'd want to join two dataframes that don't have any common columns and with same number of columns. I also tried Merge but no luck.

Below is my python script:

```py
import pandas as pd

FileFolder = r'(JAN-MAY 2021).xlsx'
BookingDF = pd.read_excel(FileFolder,skiprows=9)
BookingDF.iloc[pd.RangeIndex(len(BookingDF)).drop(1)]


VanDF = pd.read_excel(FileFolder,sheet_name='JANUARY VANSALES')

#Combine DF - with NO COMMON Columns
BookingHeader = BookingDF[['ID#','Name','w/bottles']]
VanHeader = VanDF[['Customer ID','Customer','W/BOTTLES']]

CG_DF = [BookingHeader,VanHeader]

CG = pd.concat(CG_DF, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

print(CG)
```

Current Result:

```
    ID#                       Name  w/bottles  Customer ID         Customer  W/BOTTLES
0    397414EK                   VICTORIAS       30.0          NaN              NaN        NaN
1    397414EK                   VICTORIAS       20.0          NaN              NaN        NaN
2    397414EK                   VICTORIAS        6.0          NaN              NaN        NaN
3    397414EK                   VICTORIAS        6.0          NaN              NaN        NaN
4    397414EK                   VICTORIAS       20.0          NaN              NaN        NaN
..        ...                        ...        ...          ...              ...        ...
136       NaN                        NaN        NaN       1096.0      test Store        5.0
137       NaN                        NaN        NaN       1096.0      test Store        5.0
138       NaN                        NaN        NaN       1554.0   test Pharmacy         30.0
139       NaN                        NaN        NaN       1502.0             LCJR       12.0
140       NaN                        NaN        NaN       1450.0             test        6.0
```

Expected Result:

```
   ID#            Name            w/bottles 
0    397414EK       VICTORIAS       30.0 
1    397414EK       VICTORIAS       20.0 
2    397414EK       VICTORIAS        6.0 
3    397414EK       VICTORIAS        6.0 
4    397414EK       VICTORIAS       20.0 
..        ...                        ...        ... 
136  1096          test Store        5.0
137  1096          test Store        5.0
138  1554      test Pharmacy         30.0
139  1502               LCJR         12.0
140  1450               test         6.0
```

Comment: In your expected result, you put the values from the `Customer ID` into the `ID#` column of the merged result. *How did you know they go there*, and not into the `Name` column, or the `w/bottles` column? What rule do you want to use in order to specify that? How exactly are you expecting Pandas to determine this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just rename the column headings in one of the inputs to match, and then join them up normally?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, it's like UNION ALL in SQL

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I tried to rename the columns inside DF but still no luck

Comment: So, it's implicit based on the order of the columns? Or what?

Comment: "I tried to rename the columns inside DF but still no luck" Show the exact code for this (edit your post to include it), and show what happened as a result.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, Yes, it simply on the order of the columns

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, using merge `CM = BookingHeader.merge(VanHeader)`. I've got this error .`MergeError: No common columns to perform merge`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
VanHeader.columns=BookingHeader.columns
df = pd.concat([BookingHeader,VanHeader], axis=0)
```

Comment: Works Like MAGIC ! Thanks Aneesh !